# Is there a faster query for this mysql query?

Tags: mysql, query-performance

I am working with mysql dbs. There are two columns in a particular table (column1 and column2) and 10000000+ rows. I want to get all entries where column1 is one of a list of 50000 no.s. I am using this query currently:

```
Select * from db.table where column1 in (list of 50000 no.s)
```

Is there a faster query than this?

Comment: Depends, how did you establish those 50k ids?

Comment: Consider loading the 50000 into a table

Answer (score 1):

I can not talk about MySQL - only SQL Server - but the same principle may apply.

On SQL Server an IN has a serious problem of no statistics. Which means that with a non trivial number, the query plan is a table scan.

It is better to make a temporary table and load the ID's (AND put in a unique index on it which puts up statistics) and then JOIN between the two tables. More for the query analyzer to work with.

Comment: I'd give the same advice for MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

- `INDEX(column1)`
- Are there only 2 columns in the table?  If not, then don't use `SELECT *`, but spell out the column names.
- Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`

Comment: there are only 2 columns in it.
select_type: SIMPLE;
type: ALL;
possible_keys: null;
key: null;
key_len: null;
ref: null;
rows:10000000;
Extra: null;

Can indexing column1 help? Currently they are not indexed.

Comment: Does the table have a `PRIMARY KEY`?  (Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE;` it would avoid many questions.)  `INDEX(column1)`, `INDEX(column1, column2)` should help even more. What version of MySQL are you using?  Old versions take a long time to add an index.